# Convert pandas timezone-aware DateTimeIndex to naive timestamp, but in certain timezone

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

You can use the function `tz_localize` to make a Timestamp or DateTimeIndex timezone aware, but how can you do the opposite: how can you convert a timezone aware Timestamp to a naive one, while preserving its timezone?

An example:

```
In [82]: t = pd.date_range(start="2013-05-18 12:00:00", periods=10, freq='s', tz="Europe/Brussels")

In [83]: t
Out[83]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-05-18 12:00:00, ..., 2013-05-18 12:00:09]
Length: 10, Freq: S, Timezone: Europe/Brussels
```

I could remove the timezone by setting it to None, but then the result is converted to UTC (12 o'clock became 10):

```
In [86]: t.tz = None

In [87]: t
Out[87]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-05-18 10:00:00, ..., 2013-05-18 10:00:09]
Length: 10, Freq: S, Timezone: None
```

Is there another way I can convert a DateTimeIndex to timezone naive, but while preserving the timezone it was set in?

---

Some **context** on the reason I am asking this: I want to work with timezone naive timeseries (to avoid the extra hassle with timezones, and I do not need them for the case I am working on).
But for some reason, I have to deal with a timezone-aware timeseries in my local timezone (Europe/Brussels). As all my other data are timezone naive (but represented in my local timezone), I want to convert this timeseries to naive to further work with it, but it also has to be represented in my local timezone (so just remove the timezone info, without converting the *user-visible* time to UTC).

I know the time is actually internal stored as UTC and only converted to another timezone when you represent it, so there has to be some kind of conversion when I want to "delocalize" it. For example, with the python datetime module you can "remove" the timezone like this:

```
In [119]: d = pd.Timestamp("2013-05-18 12:00:00", tz="Europe/Brussels")

In [120]: d
Out[120]: <Timestamp: 2013-05-18 12:00:00+0200 CEST, tz=Europe/Brussels>

In [121]: d.replace(tzinfo=None)
Out[121]: <Timestamp: 2013-05-18 12:00:00>
```

So, based on this, I could do the following, but I suppose this will not be very efficient when working with a larger timeseries:

```
In [124]: t
Out[124]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-05-18 12:00:00, ..., 2013-05-18 12:00:09]
Length: 10, Freq: S, Timezone: Europe/Brussels

In [125]: pd.DatetimeIndex([i.replace(tzinfo=None) for i in t])
Out[125]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-05-18 12:00:00, ..., 2013-05-18 12:00:09]
Length: 10, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Comment: Timezone=None means UTC... I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here.

Comment: I added some explanation. I want to keep the time you 'see' as a user. I hope this clarifies it a little bit.

Comment: Ah ha, it does, I didn't realise you could do that with `replace`.

Comment: @AndyHayden So actually what I want is the exact inverse of `tz_localize` which is what the `replace(tzinfo=None)` does for datetimes, but it is indeed not a very obvious way.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

To answer my own question, this functionality has been added to pandas in the meantime. Starting **from pandas 0.15.0**, you can use `tz_localize(None)` to remove the timezone resulting in local time.
See the whatsnew entry: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#timezone-handling-improvements

So with my example from above:

```
In [4]: t = pd.date_range(start="2013-05-18 12:00:00", periods=2, freq='H',
                          tz= "Europe/Brussels")

In [5]: t
Out[5]: DatetimeIndex(['2013-05-18 12:00:00+02:00', '2013-05-18 13:00:00+02:00'],
                       dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Brussels]', freq='H')
```

using `tz_localize(None)` removes the timezone information resulting in **naive local time**:

```
In [6]: t.tz_localize(None)
Out[6]: DatetimeIndex(['2013-05-18 12:00:00', '2013-05-18 13:00:00'], 
                      dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

Further, you can also use `tz_convert(None)` to remove the timezone information but converting to UTC, so yielding **naive UTC time**:

```
In [7]: t.tz_convert(None)
Out[7]: DatetimeIndex(['2013-05-18 10:00:00', '2013-05-18 11:00:00'], 
                      dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

---

This is much **more performant** than the `datetime.replace` solution:

```
In [31]: t = pd.date_range(start="2013-05-18 12:00:00", periods=10000, freq='H',
                           tz="Europe/Brussels")

In [32]: %timeit t.tz_localize(None)
1000 loops, best of 3: 233 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit pd.DatetimeIndex([i.replace(tzinfo=None) for i in t])
10 loops, best of 3: 99.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: In case you're working with something that's already UTC and need to convert it to local time and _then_ drop the timezone: `from tzlocal import get_localzone`, `tz_here = get_localzone()`, `<datetime object>.tz_convert(tz_here).tz_localize(None)`

Comment: If you don't have a useful index, you may need `t.dt.tz_localize(None)` or `t.dt.tz_convert(None)`. Note the `.dt`.

Comment: This solution only works when there is one unique tz in the Series. If you have multiple different tz in the same Series, then see (and upvote) the solution here :-) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204751/1054154

Answer (score 55):

Because I always struggle to remember, a quick summary of what each of these do:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp.now()  # naive local time
Timestamp('2019-10-07 10:30:19.428748')

>>> pd.Timestamp.utcnow()  # tz aware UTC
Timestamp('2019-10-07 08:30:19.428748+0000', tz='UTC')

>>> pd.Timestamp.now(tz='Europe/Brussels')  # tz aware local time
Timestamp('2019-10-07 10:30:19.428748+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels')

>>> pd.Timestamp.now(tz='Europe/Brussels').tz_localize(None)  # naive local time
Timestamp('2019-10-07 10:30:19.428748')

>>> pd.Timestamp.now(tz='Europe/Brussels').tz_convert(None)  # naive UTC
Timestamp('2019-10-07 08:30:19.428748')

>>> pd.Timestamp.utcnow().tz_localize(None)  # naive UTC
Timestamp('2019-10-07 08:30:19.428748')

>>> pd.Timestamp.utcnow().tz_convert(None)  # naive UTC
Timestamp('2019-10-07 08:30:19.428748')
```

Comment: What is "naive"?! Is it "non-tz-aware"?

Comment: It may seem so simple, but I can't figure out how to replace this template pd.Timestamp with an actual Timestamp column in a dataframe. I have a string and need to make it tz aware of a particular tz.

Comment: @PM0087 "naive" just means a timestamp without a tz. / For your follow up, you might have better luck by asking a new question.

Answer (score 19):

I think you can't achieve what you want in a more efficient manner than you proposed.

The underlying problem is that the timestamps (as you seem aware) are made up of two parts.  The data that represents the UTC time, and the timezone, tz_info.  The timezone information is used only for display purposes when printing the timezone to the screen.  At display time, the data is offset appropriately and +01:00 (or similar) is added to the string.  Stripping off the tz_info value (using tz_convert(tz=None)) doesn't doesn't actually change the data that represents the naive part of the timestamp.

So, the only way to do what you want is to modify the underlying data (pandas doesn't allow this... DatetimeIndex are immutable -- see the help on DatetimeIndex), or to create a new set of timestamp objects and wrap them in a new DatetimeIndex.  Your solution does the latter:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex([i.replace(tzinfo=None) for i in t])
```

For reference, here is the `replace` method of `Timestamp` (see tslib.pyx):

```
def replace(self, **kwds):
    return Timestamp(datetime.replace(self, **kwds),
                     offset=self.offset)
```

You can refer to the docs on `datetime.datetime` to see that `datetime.datetime.replace` also creates a new object.

If you can, your best bet for efficiency is to modify the source of the data so that it (incorrectly) reports the timestamps without their timezone.  You mentioned:

> I want to work with timezone naive timeseries (to avoid the extra hassle with timezones, and I do not need them for the case I am working on)

I'd be curious what extra hassle you are referring to.  I recommend as a general rule for all software development, keep your timestamp 'naive values' in UTC.  There is little worse than looking at two different int64 values wondering which timezone they belong to.  If you always, always, always use UTC for the internal storage, then you will avoid countless headaches.  My mantra is **Timezones are for human I/O only**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and a late reply: my case is not an application, just a scientific analysis for my own work (so eg no sharing with collaborators over the world). And in that case, it can be easier to just work with naive timestamps, but in your local time. So I don't have to worry about time zones and just can interprete the timestamp as local time (the extra 'hassle' can be eg that everything then has to be in timezones, otherwise you get things like "can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes").
But I completely agree with you when dealing with more complex applications.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted solution does not work when there are multiple different timezones in a Series. It throws `ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`

The solution is to use the `apply` method.

Please see the examples below:

```
# Let's have a series `a` with different multiple timezones. 
> a
0    2019-10-04 16:30:00+02:00
1    2019-10-07 16:00:00-04:00
2    2019-09-24 08:30:00-07:00
Name: localized, dtype: object

> a.iloc[0]
Timestamp('2019-10-04 16:30:00+0200', tz='Europe/Amsterdam')

# trying the accepted solution
> a.dt.tz_localize(None)
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True

# Make it tz-naive. This is the solution:
> a.apply(lambda x:x.tz_localize(None))
0   2019-10-04 16:30:00
1   2019-10-07 16:00:00
2   2019-09-24 08:30:00
Name: localized, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# a.tz_convert() also does not work with multiple timezones, but this works:
> a.apply(lambda x:x.tz_convert('America/Los_Angeles'))
0   2019-10-04 07:30:00-07:00
1   2019-10-07 13:00:00-07:00
2   2019-09-24 08:30:00-07:00
Name: localized, dtype: datetime64[ns, America/Los_Angeles]
```

Answer (score 8):

Setting the `tz` attribute of the index explicitly seems to work:

```
ts_utc = ts.tz_convert("UTC")
ts_utc.index.tz = None
```

Comment: Late comment, but I want the result to be the time represented in the local time zone, not in UTC. And as I show in the question, setting the `tz` to None also converts it to UTC.

Comment: Further, the timeseries is already timezone aware, so calling `tz_convert` on it will raise an error.

Answer (score 6):

Late contribution but just came across something similar in [Python datetime and pandas give different timestamps for the same date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645239/python-datetime-and-pandas-give-different-timestamps-for-the-same-date).

If you have timezone-aware datetime in `pandas`, **technically, `tz_localize(None)` changes the POSIX timestamp (that is used internally) as if the local time from the timestamp was UTC.** *Local* in this context means *local in the specified timezone*. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

t = pd.date_range(start="2013-05-18 12:00:00", periods=2, freq='H', tz="US/Central")
# DatetimeIndex(['2013-05-18 12:00:00-05:00', '2013-05-18 13:00:00-05:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, US/Central]', freq='H')

t_loc = t.tz_localize(None)
# DatetimeIndex(['2013-05-18 12:00:00', '2013-05-18 13:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')

# offset in seconds according to timezone:
(t_loc.values-t.values)//1e9
# array([-18000, -18000], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

Note that this will leave you with **strange things during DST transitions**, e.g.

```
t = pd.date_range(start="2020-03-08 01:00:00", periods=2, freq='H', tz="US/Central")
(t.values[1]-t.values[0])//1e9
# numpy.timedelta64(3600,'ns')

t_loc = t.tz_localize(None)
(t_loc.values[1]-t_loc.values[0])//1e9
# numpy.timedelta64(7200,'ns')
```

In contrast, `tz_convert(None)` does not modify the internal timestamp, it just removes the `tzinfo`.

```
t_utc = t.tz_convert(None)
(t_utc.values-t.values)//1e9
# array([0, 0], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

---

My bottom line would be: stick with timezone-aware datetime if you can or only use `t.tz_convert(None)` which doesn't modify the underlying POSIX timestamp. Just keep in mind that you're practically working with UTC then.

(Python 3.8.2 x64 on Windows 10, `pandas` v1.0.5.)

Comment: ha, a quick SO search landed me here, where you explained in details for DST transition problem in other libraries.

Comment: @stucash yeah, this is basically the same thing in polars. Although timezone / aware datetime handling is still under developement (I hope) for polars. There are related, open issues like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75268283/10197418).

Answer (score 4):

Building on D.A.'s suggestion that "*the only way to do what you want is to modify the underlying data*" and using numpy to modify the underlying data...

This works for me, and is pretty fast:

```
def tz_to_naive(datetime_index):
    """Converts a tz-aware DatetimeIndex into a tz-naive DatetimeIndex,
    effectively baking the timezone into the internal representation.

    Parameters
    ----------
    datetime_index : pandas.DatetimeIndex, tz-aware

    Returns
    -------
    pandas.DatetimeIndex, tz-naive
    """
    # Calculate timezone offset relative to UTC
    timestamp = datetime_index[0]
    tz_offset = (timestamp.replace(tzinfo=None) - 
                 timestamp.tz_convert('UTC').replace(tzinfo=None))
    tz_offset_td64 = np.timedelta64(tz_offset)

    # Now convert to naive DatetimeIndex
    return pd.DatetimeIndex(datetime_index.values + tz_offset_td64)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I think this will only work if there is no summertime/wintertime transition in the period of the dataset.

Comment: @joris Ah, good catch!  I hadn't considered that!  I'll modify my solution to handle this situation ASAP.

Comment: I believe this is still wrong as you are only calculating the offset of the first time and not as it progress throughout time. This will cause you to miss the daylight saving time and not adjust accordingly on that given date and onward.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is add `tzinfo` when you define a datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from tzinfo_examples import HOUR, Eastern
u0 = datetime(2016, 3, 13, 5, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
for i in range(4):
     u = u0 + i*HOUR
     t = u.astimezone(Eastern)
     print(u.time(), 'UTC =', t.time(), t.tzname())
```

Answer (score 0):

## How I handled this problem with a 15-min frequency datetimeindex in europe.

If you are in the situation where you have a **timezone aware** (`Europe/Amsterdam` in my case) index and want to convert it into a **timezone naive** index by transforming everything into local time, you will have dst problems, namely

- there will be 1 hour missing on the last sunday of march (when europe switches to summer time)
- there will be 1 hour duplicate on the last sunday of october (when europe switches to summer time)

Here is how you can handle it:

```py
# make index tz naive
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None)

# handle dst
if df.index[0].month == 3:
    # last sunday of march, one hour is lost
    df = df.resample("15min").pad()

if df.index[0].month == 10:
    # in october, one hour is added
    df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

**Note: in my case, I run the above code on a `df` that contains only a single month, hence I do `df.index[0].month` to find out the month. If yours contains more months, you should probably index it differently to know when to do DST.**

It consists of resampling from the last valid value in march, to avoid losing the 1 hour (in my case, all my data is in 15 min intervals, hence i resample like that. Resample for whatever your interval is). And for october, I drop duplicates.