# How to work with a Dataframe with a column/series of dtype object and having different +z values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

Hi I have a dataframe with one of its column called 'Formatted Date' having objects like `2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200`. I am trying to convert it to datetime and and I used

```
format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z'
```

It does not work since the +z value is not the same for all. How do I first make the time zones same?

```
df['Formatted Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Formatted Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')
```

Comment: That format looks correct. Are you sure all rows have correctly formatted values?

Comment: Please share the exact error message and some example data that causes the error where you didn't expect it.

Comment: @sharon Please [edit] the question instead of using comments. Comments intentionally don't support code blocks.

Comment: All i found my answer in the below. Thanks for responding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385497/how-can-i-convert-my-datetime-column-in-pandas-all-to-the-same-timezone

Answer (score 0):

Parse to datetime with keyword `utc=True`. If you don't know the origin time zone of the data, I'd suggest to continue working with UTC here. However if you know the time zone, you can `tz_convert` to it, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Formatted Date': ["2006-02-01 00:00:00.000 +0100", 
                                      "2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200"]})
df['Formatted Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Formatted Date'], utc=True)

# df['Formatted Date']
# 0   2006-01-31 23:00:00+00:00
# 1   2006-03-31 22:00:00+00:00
# Name: Formatted Date, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

df['Formatted Date'] = df['Formatted Date'].dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')

df['Formatted Date'] 
0   2006-02-01 00:00:00+01:00
1   2006-04-01 00:00:00+02:00
Name: Formatted Date, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

Comment: @sharonchetia I didn't notice that you already found a solution, as you mention in the comments section. I suggested to close the question as a duplicate; but you might as well leave it here for others to find the other question as well.