# How to convert a column of epoch time to datetime - OverflowError

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list of epoch timestamps in a column in my `df` which is `df['DateTime']` (Note they dont have `[]` in the actual column:

```
 [1.59549158e+12]
 [1.59549322e+12]
 [1.59549322e+12]
 [1.59549322e+12]
 [1.59549322e+12]
 [1.59549522e+12]
 [1.59549685e+12]
 [1.59549685e+12]
 [1.59549685e+12]
 [1.59549784e+12]
 [1.59549784e+12]
 [1.59549871e+12]
 [1.59549969e+12]
 [1.59549969e+12]
 [1.59556182e+12]
 [1.59556182e+12]
 [1.59556661e+12]
 [1.59556661e+12]
 [1.59556661e+12]
 [1.59556661e+12]
 [1.59556833e+12]
 [1.59556939e+12]
 [1.59557079e+12]
 [1.59557079e+12]
 [1.59557246e+12]
 [1.59557246e+12]
 [1.59557335e+12]
 [1.59557335e+12]
 [1.59557335e+12]
 [1.59557564e+12]
 [1.59557564e+12]
 [1.59557564e+12]
 [1.59557603e+12]
 [1.59557603e+12]
```

Looking through the documentation and on StackOverflow I have tried the following code to convert those into a timestamp:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],unit='s')
```

But I am getting an error saying

`OverflowError: int too big to convert`

and also

`pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input 1595482694074.0 with the unit 's'`

Does anyone know what these errors mean and how to get around it. It says `int too big to convert` but as a data type it is a `float64`. I am trying to convert to an Australian timezone ideally. If anyone has any ideas that would be great! Thanks very much!

Comment: Try `unit = 'ms'`, seems to work

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(1595482694074,unit='ms')`

Comment: ah thats perfect -thanks heaps!

Comment: and then to convert to Australia time?

Comment: add `.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Queensland')` at the end of your time conversion call (if original time is in UTC that is)

Comment: thanks that worked - however now im getting the format `2020-07-23 16:06:39.420000+10:00` which seems to no be compatible with excel. Would this then be converting the datetime to a shortened format? Something like `2020-07-23 16:06:39`

Comment: check (skip out on `.dt` though, like with Australia conversion) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789888/convert-datetime-columns-to-a-different-timezone-pandas

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. when i did the `.dt.tz_localize(None)` after it put it in the correct format. so in total the coded ended up being `df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('utc').dt.tz_convert('Australia/Melbourne').dt.tz_localize(None))`. Thanks @dm2 for your help!