# How to read timezone aware datetimes as a timezone naive local DatetimeIndex with read_csv in pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

When I use pandas read_csv to read a column with a timezone aware datetime (and specify this column to be the index), pandas converts it to a **timezone naive utc** DatetimeIndex.

Data in Test.csv:

`DateTime,Temperature
2016-07-01T11:05:07+02:00,21.125
2016-07-01T11:05:09+02:00,21.138
2016-07-01T11:05:10+02:00,21.156
2016-07-01T11:05:11+02:00,21.179
2016-07-01T11:05:12+02:00,21.198
2016-07-01T11:05:13+02:00,21.206
2016-07-01T11:05:14+02:00,21.225
2016-07-01T11:05:15+02:00,21.233`

Code to read from csv:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

This results in an index that represents the timezone naive utc time:

```
In [3]: df.index

Out[3]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-01 09:05:07', '2016-07-01 09:05:09',
           '2016-07-01 09:05:10', '2016-07-01 09:05:11',
           '2016-07-01 09:05:12', '2016-07-01 09:05:13',
           '2016-07-01 09:05:14', '2016-07-01 09:05:15'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DateTime', freq=None)
```

I tried to use a date_parser function:

```
In [4]: date_parser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).tz_localize(None)

In [5]: df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, date_parser=date_parser)
```

This gave the same result.

How can I make read_csv create a DatetimeIndex that is **timezone naive** and represents the **local time** instead of the **utc time**?

I'm using pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628819/convert-pandas-timezone-aware-datetimeindex-to-naive-timestamp-but-in-certain-t?rq=1)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But that specific question is about dealing with timezone information that is actually there. In my question, pandas.read_csv loses the timezone information by converting the datetime read from the csv to a timezone naive utc datetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38532026/1504026) of Alex leads to a timezone aware DatetimeIndex. To get a **timezone naive local** DatetimeIndex, as asked by the OP, inform `dateutil.parser.parser` to ignore the timezone information by setting `ignoretz=True`:

```
import dateutil

date_parser = lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x, ignoretz=True)
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, date_parser=date_parser)

print(df)
```

outputs

```
                     Temperature
DateTime                        
2016-07-01 11:05:07       21.125
2016-07-01 11:05:09       21.138
2016-07-01 11:05:10       21.156
2016-07-01 11:05:11       21.179
2016-07-01 11:05:12       21.198
2016-07-01 11:05:13       21.206
2016-07-01 11:05:14       21.225
2016-07-01 11:05:15       21.233
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) the default `date_parser` uses `dateutil.parser.parser`. According to [the docs for that function](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse), the default is to ignore timezones. So if you supply `dateutil.parser.parser` as the `date_parser` kwarg, timezones are not converted.

```
import dateutil

df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, date_parser=dateutil.parser.parse)

print(df)
```

outputs

```
                           Temperature
DateTime                              
2016-07-01 11:05:07+02:00       21.125
2016-07-01 11:05:09+02:00       21.138
2016-07-01 11:05:10+02:00       21.156
2016-07-01 11:05:11+02:00       21.179
2016-07-01 11:05:12+02:00       21.198
2016-07-01 11:05:13+02:00       21.206
2016-07-01 11:05:14+02:00       21.225
2016-07-01 11:05:15+02:00       21.233
```

Comment: This answer is certainly helpful, but leads to a timezone aware DatetimeIndex. Adding the argument `ignoretz=True` in the parsing function gives the desired timezone naive DatetimeIndex. I added this as a new answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I adopted the `dateutil` technique earlier today but have since switched to a faster alternative:

```
date_parser = lambda ts: pd.to_datetime([s[:-5] for s in ts]))
```

> Edit: `s[:-5]` is correct (screenshot has error)

In the screenshot below, I import ~55MB of tab-separated files. The `dateutil` method works, but takes orders of magnitude longer.

[image]

This was using pandas 0.18.1 and dateutil 2.5.3.

---

*EDIT This lambda function will work even if `Z-0000` suffix is missing...*

```
date_parser = lambda ts: pd.to_datetime([s[:-5] if 'Z' in s else s for s in ts])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can even try :

```
date_parser = lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x.str[:-6])
```

Comment: A [virtually identical solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39156778/11301900) was already posted 4 years ago.