# how to remove + from datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have converted datetime to "Europe/Paris" format.

```
datetime
2016-07-15 8:32:02

df['datetime']=df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize("Europe/Paris")

Output:
2016-07-15 8:32:02+02:00
```

I want to remove `+02:00` from this datetime and I am expecting to have the following

```
2016-07-15 10:32:02
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: It looks like all `.dt.tz_localize("Europe/Paris")` is doing is to add the `+2:00`. Why not just remove it?

Comment: I want to convert the time to `Europe/Paris` using `.dt.tz_localize("Europe/Paris")` and at the same time I don't want `+2:00`

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect is correct, if you do `df['datetime'].dt.tz_convert(None)` you get `2016-07-15 06:32:02` not `2016-07-15 10:32:02`

Comment: If you'd localised the datetimes to GMT first and then converted then you get the following: `In [85]:
df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize("GMT").dt.tz_convert("Europe/Paris")
Out[85]:
0   2016-07-15 10:32:02+02:00`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert pandas timezone-aware DateTimeIndex to naive timestamp, but in certain timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628819/convert-pandas-timezone-aware-datetimeindex-to-naive-timestamp-but-in-certain-t)

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/StamKaly/ip-to-local-time/blob/master/get/localt.py#L7). It might help if you are using `pytz`, otherwise, start using it :P

Comment: When I import this date variable to Tableau, it is treating it as a string variable. if I can add two hours to `datetime` variable without `+02:00` might solve the issue.