# How to convert dates to one format in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

Honestly, I'm confused.

I've got 2 datasets with different datetime formats.

One has `2019-04-13T18:30:16Z` format

Another has `01.04.2019 18:57:00` format

I merged two datasets into a dataframe and I need to compare two dates in `df.query('date1 == date2')`

I get this error: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects

I tried `df['datetime_1'] = df['datetime_1'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')`.
Then I tried `df['datetime_1'] = df['datetime_1'].dt.tz_convert('UTC')`

I decided to do this because

```
pandas.to_datetime('2019-04-13T18:30:16Z')
```

returns `Timestamp('2017-01-12 20:50:10+0000', tz='UTC')`

But I still get the same error.

How can I unify both formats?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628819/convert-pandas-timezone-aware-datetimeindex-to-naive-timestamp-but-in-certain-t

Comment: In what version of Pandas does `pd.to_datetime('2019-04-13T18:30:16Z')` produce that?

Comment: I use 0.24.1 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dt.tz_localize(None) helped me