# How can I convert the string '2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z' into a datetime object?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

As the question says, I have a series of strings like `'2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z'`. How can I convert this series to `datetime` using Python? I prefer the method on pandas. If not is there any method to solve this task? Thank all.

```
string '2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z' 
convert to 2020-01-06 00:00:00 under datetime object
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: a simple way how to handle the Z and parse to aware datetime / UTC: [replace with +00:00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With Python 3.7+, that can be achieved with [`datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) and some *tweaking* of the source string:

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime.fromisoformat('2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z'[:-1] + '+00:00')
```

Output:

`datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`

And here is a more *Pythonic* way to achieve the same result:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

datetime.fromisoformat(
    '2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z'[:-1]
).astimezone(timezone.utc)
```

Output:

`datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 6, 3, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`

Finally, to format it as `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, you can do:

```py
d = datetime.fromisoformat(
    '2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z'[:-1]
).astimezone(timezone.utc)
d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

`'2020-01-06 00:00:00'`

Comment: just stripping the `Z` can be a bad idea since that will result in a naive datetime object - which Python treats as *local time*, not UTC (which is specified by Z)

Comment: @MrFuppes, thanks for the heads-up. I updated the answer to work around that.

Comment: ... using what you suggested in the main comments.

Answer (score 6):

Given `raw_time` is column contains the string time. You can do this

```
pd.to_datetime(df['raw_time'])
```

Comment: This method will create 2020-01-06 00:00:00+00:00. I would like to have the datetime under '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', without +00:00

Comment: Then you only need to use strftime on that column.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [python-dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil)

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.isoparse("2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want pandas method try this:

```
sample series `s`

Out[1792]:
0    2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z
1    2020-01-06T01:00:00.000Z
dtype: object

s_time = pd.to_datetime(s).dt.tz_localize(None)

Out[1796]:
0   2020-01-06 00:00:00
1   2020-01-06 01:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: note: [this might change more than you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656878/10197418).