# How do I convert 2020-03-20T04:00:00.000Z string to DateTime in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new in Python.My datetime parameter is `2020-03-20T04:00:00.000Z`. How can I convert it to datetime & how can separate in date & time.
My code spinet are bellow:

```
schedule_time = models.DateTimeField() #This is my model code
```

My view code for queryset are:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = AppointmentSerial.objects.all()
    status = self.request.query_params.get('status')
    schedule_time = self.request.query_params.get('schedule_time')

    if not status:
        queryset = queryset.exclude(status="DELETE")

    if schedule_time:
        dateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(schedule_time, "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S")
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTime, "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y,%m,%d")
        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTime, "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S").strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        if time == '00:00:00':
            queryset = queryset.filter(schedule_time_date=datetime.date(date))
        else:
            queryset = queryset.filter(schedule_time=schedule_time)
    return queryset
```

Also how can I query by date value of a datetime field when time is 0 ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code so we can help you.

Comment: Also, are you trying to just display a date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert the string '2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z' to datetime in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744589/how-can-i-convert-the-string-2020-01-06t000000-000z-to-datetime-in-python)