# convert datetime64[ns, UTC] pandas column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe which has timestamp and its datatype is object.

```
0    2020-07-09T04:23:50.267Z
1    2020-07-09T11:21:55.536Z
2    2020-07-09T11:23:18.015Z
3    2020-07-09T04:03:28.581Z
4    2020-07-09T04:03:33.874Z
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

I am not aware of the format of the datetime in the above dataframe. I applied **pd.to_datetime** to the above column where the datatype is changed as **datetime64[ns, UTC]**.

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
```

Now the dataframe looks in this way,

```
0   2020-07-09 04:23:50.267000+00:00
1   2020-07-09 11:21:55.536000+00:00
2   2020-07-09 11:23:18.015000+00:00
3   2020-07-09 04:03:28.581000+00:00
4   2020-07-09 04:03:33.874000+00:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

I want to convert the above datetime64[ns, UTC] format to normal datetime.

```
For example,
2020-07-09 04:23:50.267000+00:00  to 2020-07-09 04:23:50
```

Can anyone explain me what is the meaning of this **2020-07-09T04:23:50.267Z** representation and also how to convert this into datetime object?

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628819/convert-pandas-timezone-aware-datetimeindex-to-naive-timestamp-but-in-certain-t

Comment: `2020-07-09T04:23:50.267Z` is an [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date/time string. `Z` stands for zulu time and means UTC.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To remove timezone, use `tz_localize`:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Output:

```
                timestamp
0 2020-07-09 04:23:50.267
1 2020-07-09 11:21:55.536
2 2020-07-09 11:23:18.015
3 2020-07-09 04:03:28.581
4 2020-07-09 04:03:33.874
```

Comment: since the input already refers to UTC, I'd suggest to convert to None, not localize, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656878/10197418).

Answer (score 4):

Return of to_datetime depends [confusingly to me] on the type of input:

```
list-like: DatetimeIndex
Series: Series of datetime64 dtype
scalar: Timestamp
```

So the following fails

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["StringArray"])
xm = df["Time"] < pd.to_datetime("12/29/2020  9:09:37 PM")
```

but the following works just fine

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["StringArray"])
xm = df["Time"] < pd.to_datetime("12/29/2020  9:09:37 PM", utc=True)
```

This may help you avoid timezone problems. Regards,

Comment: I am struggling to make a comparison using np.isnat work if df["Time"] has any values of NaT in datetime64[ns, UTC]. (if `xm = ((np.isnat(df["Time"])) | (df["Time"] < pd.to_datetime("12/29/2020  9:09:37 PM", utc=True)))`  I receive `TypeError: ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for np.datetime64 and np.timedelta64.`  so, tz_localize may be required? (note that pandas has a pd.NaT constant, but not a pd.isnat() or pd.Timestamp.isnat() function)