# How to remove microseconds from DateTimeIndex in dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, type-conversion

I want to remove the microseconds from index.

My index is like this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2003-11-20 13:07:40.895000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:16:13.039000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:24:44.868000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:33:17.013000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:41:49.158000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:50:20.987000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:58:53.132000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 14:07:24.961000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 14:15:57.106000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 14:24:28.935000+00:00',
           ...
           '2003-12-04 19:28:56.025000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 19:37:27.854000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 19:45:59.999000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 19:54:32.143000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:03:03.972000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:11:36.117000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:20:07.946000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:28:40.091000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:37:11.920000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:45:44.065000+00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]'
```

And I want to remove the microseconds in order to have something like this only: `'2003-12-04 20:45:44'`
I do not want to convert it to string, as it is needed to remain datetime because it is the index of the dataframe.
I have been searching for this, but I only found this, which does not work:

```
df.index.replace(microsecond=0, inplace = True)
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Try `df.index.floor('S')`

Comment: I get this result: '2003-11-20 13:07:40+00:00'

Comment: That +00:00 is timezone information, you don't need that then try: `didx.floor('S').tz_localize(None)`

Comment: try `df.index.astype('datetime64[s]')`

Comment: also `idx.floor('S')'.tz_convert(None)`... so the difference is when you want to change timezones, `tz_convert` will change the time to what it would be in the new tz, `tz_localize` keeps times the same and just stamps the new tz

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [convert pandas tz aware to naive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16628819/6692898)

Comment: "Cannot cast DatetimeArray to dtype datetime64[s]" @Terry

Comment: It worked!!! @Scott Boston

Comment: it worked!! @Richie V | thank you all very much!!

Comment: you can keep the microseconds for later use with `idx.microsecond` which will return a numpy array of integers... [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/indexing.html#datetimeindex) are a great source

Comment: @Scott Boston can you write your answer in a comment in order to be better visualized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a pd.DateTimeIndex with timezone information and millisecond data like this:

```
didx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2003-11-20 13:07:40.895000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:16:13.039000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:24:44.868000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:33:17.013000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:41:49.158000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:50:20.987000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 13:58:53.132000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 14:07:24.961000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 14:15:57.106000+00:00',
           '2003-11-20 14:24:28.935000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 19:28:56.025000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 19:37:27.854000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 19:45:59.999000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 19:54:32.143000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:03:03.972000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:11:36.117000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:20:07.946000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:28:40.091000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:37:11.920000+00:00',
           '2003-12-04 20:45:44.065000+00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]')
```

You can use `pd.DateTimeIndex.floor` and `tz_localize(None)`, to truncate timestamps to seconds and remove the timezone information.

```
didx.floor('S').tz_localize(None)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2003-11-20 13:07:40', '2003-11-20 13:16:13',
               '2003-11-20 13:24:44', '2003-11-20 13:33:17',
               '2003-11-20 13:41:49', '2003-11-20 13:50:20',
               '2003-11-20 13:58:53', '2003-11-20 14:07:24',
               '2003-11-20 14:15:57', '2003-11-20 14:24:28',
               '2003-12-04 19:28:56', '2003-12-04 19:37:27',
               '2003-12-04 19:45:59', '2003-12-04 19:54:32',
               '2003-12-04 20:03:03', '2003-12-04 20:11:36',
               '2003-12-04 20:20:07', '2003-12-04 20:28:40',
               '2003-12-04 20:37:11', '2003-12-04 20:45:44'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` on each.

Comment: Yes, it worked, but it transformed the index into String.

Comment: Can you try https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: This would allow you to pass a datetime object, format as needed, and return as a datetime object.

so datetime.strptime( {date_time object}, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: it is great to have several options... this is not as efficient as Scott's comment, yet it gets the job done