# Transform datetime column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

I don't know how to transform data in my column 'datetime' with this format:

```
2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

in to:

```
Jan-2020
```

I've tried with this:

```
works_data["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(works_data["datetime"], utc=True).dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
```

but doesn't work. It returns the date in that format but with one less month. For example, for `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00` returns `Dec-2019`, and I don't know why.

How can I resolve this problem?

### Edit

The actual code that is working:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import datetime
import time

url = "https://apidatos.ree.es/es/datos/generacion/estructura-generacion?start_date=2020-01-01T00:00&end_date=2020-12-31T22:00&time_trunc=month"


response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['included'])


works_data = pd.json_normalize(data=df['attributes'], record_path='values', 
                            meta=['title'])
```

And if I print the works_data, it returns:

```
value   percentage  datetime    title
0   3.726053e+06    0.163889    2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00   Hidráulica
1   2.837911e+06    0.139561    2020-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00   Hidráulica
2   3.112718e+06    0.148076    2020-03-01T00:00:00.000+01:00   Hidráulica
3   2.861429e+06    0.163464    2020-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00   Hidráulica
4   2.858050e+06    0.159065    2020-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00   Hidráulica
... ... ... ... ...
107 3.504687e+04    0.002002    2020-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00   Residuos renovables
108 3.665093e+04    0.002040    2020-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00   Residuos renovables
109 4.231355e+04    0.002197    2020-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00   Residuos renovables
110 4.313452e+04    0.001803    2020-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00   Residuos renovables
111 3.159610e+04    0.003548    2020-08-01T00:00:00.000+02:00   Residuos renovables
```

How can I continue to transform the datetime column?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me given the timezone is `+1`, i.e, `2020-01-01 00:00:00` in `+01:00` timezone is still in `2019` at GMT timezone.

Comment: so.. how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quang Hoang already mentioned, you are converting UTC+1 into UTC, which is one hour back. Ergo,`pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", utc=True)` resolves to `Timestamp('2019-12-31 23:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')`

It seems like you don't want to convert the date into UTC, so don't set the corresponding parameter to `True`.

### Converting Strings

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00").strftime("%b-%Y")
>>> 'Jan-2020'
```

Alternatively, using only the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.fromisoformat("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00").strftime("%b-%Y")
>>> 'Jan-2020'
```

### Converting Series

If you want to convert the entire column of datetimes, either use list comprehension or Pandas `Series.dt.strftime` function.

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.Series(["2020-03-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00", "2020-06-01T00:00:00.000+01:00"])
pd.to_datetime(dates).dt.strftime("%b-%Y")

>>> 0    Mar-2020
>>> 1    Jan-2020
>>> 2    Jun-2020
>>> dtype: object
```

**The above approach will fail when you have different timezone offsets in your Series.** You will receive a `ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`. In such a case, you can use `apply` to remove the timezone information for each datetime or use a list comprehension as follows.

```
df["column"] = [pd.to_datetime(date).strftime("%b-%Y") for date in dates]
```

Comment: Hi @sabacherli Thanks for answering!! If I don't set the utc=True, i have this error....Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True

Comment: If I use your first option // `pd.to_datetime(works_data["datetime"]).strftime("%b-%Y")`      I have this error.... 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: For more info, my 'datetime' column is a Dtype = object

Comment: I have the same problem....`Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`

Comment: I just post all my code, could you please check it?

Comment: `works_data["datetime"] = [pd.to_datetime(date).strftime("%b-%Y") for date in works_data["datetime"]]` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed UTC offset: localize the date/time column to `None` before `strftime`:

```
pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00").tz_localize(None).strftime('%b-%Y')
Out[47]: 'Jan-2020'
```

See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656878/10197418) to get more info what's happening in the background.

---

Since your input seems to contain ***mixed UTC offsets***, conversion via `to_datetime` will yield a Series of `datetime.datetime` objects (dtype object, as opposed to dtype datetime64). You'll need to replace the `tzinfo` property with `None`:

```
pd.to_datetime(works_data["datetime"]).apply(lambda t: t.replace(tzinfo=None)).dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFruppes  I've tried it but returns me this.... `index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex`

Comment: @rogarui: hm, seems like you want to apply this to your df's index and it wasn't casted `to_datetime` before?

Comment: I don't know what is happening...i have created my df and when I try to transform the column returns me so many errors... do you prefer if i post the entire code?

Comment: I just post all my code, could you please check it? @MrFuppes

Comment: @rogarui - your data contains mixed UTC offsets. `pd.to_datetime` fails to infer the according `pytz.fixed_offset`s, so... time for a `lambda` :) (see the edit of my answer)