# How to eliminate timezone specification?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc

I converted my `Time` column to `datetime` values using this code:

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'],utc=True)
```

These are UTC timestamps whcih is fine.

The column looks now like this:

[image]

I now want to eliminate the timezone specification `+00:00` for each of the dates. How could I do this?

Comment: `.dt.tz_localize(None)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pandas timezone-aware DateTimeIndex to naive timestamp, but in certain timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628819/convert-pandas-timezone-aware-datetimeindex-to-naive-timestamp-but-in-certain-t)