# Exclude time zone information in datatime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

datatime available as object

[image]

converting to datetime type

```
df[['x','y']] = df[['x','y']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z', errors='coerce')
```

here I want to exclude time zone information 'UTC'

output data type
[image]

Comment: It's best to [not use images for error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). The text will be of help for those that use assistive technologies and also allows for your error message to be indexed by search engines, possibly helping others in the future.

Comment: I suspect you neither need `apply` nor provide a `format` to pd.to_datetime. Then, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/16628819/10197418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code sample, I see that you are wanting to process multiple variables at once. In this case, you can exclude the time zone information by using a lambda function to apply the `pd.to_datetime` function and extract the time zone naive timestamps with the [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) property. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd  # v 1.1.3

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=['2020-12-30 12:00:00 UTC', '2020-12-30 13:00:00 UTC',
                          '2020-12-30 14:00:00 UTC', '2020-12-30 15:00:00 UTC',
                          '2020-12-30 16:00:00 UTC'],
                       y=['2020-12-31 01:00:00 UTC', '2020-12-31 04:00:00 UTC',
                          '2020-12-31 02:00:00 UTC', '2020-12-31 05:00:00 UTC',
                          '2020-12-31 03:00:00 UTC']))

df[['x','y']] = df[['x','y']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).values)
print(df[['x','y']])
#                      x                   y
#  0 2020-12-30 12:00:00 2020-12-31 01:00:00
#  1 2020-12-30 13:00:00 2020-12-31 04:00:00
#  2 2020-12-30 14:00:00 2020-12-31 02:00:00
#  3 2020-12-30 15:00:00 2020-12-31 05:00:00
#  4 2020-12-30 16:00:00 2020-12-31 03:00:00
```