# pd.to_datetime() return types can vary wildly based on input. How do I ensure it doesn't return a Series/Array with dtype 'object'?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This question is a bit more extended than just the title. I'm using pandas 1.1.5 for the record.

The function `pd.to_datetime(x)` is a bit wild and the returned object depends on the argument. When the `x` is a array-like, containing strings such as `2021-03-01 01:30:19.580882000 +0100`:

1. If `x` is a `np.array`, then it will return either:

   a) **In the ideal case**: a `pd.DatetimeIndex` with `dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]'`

   b) If something unknown goes wrong: a `pd.Index` with `dtype='object'` filled (mostly or completely) with `datetime.datetime` objects (this can lead to problems as explained later)
2. If `x` is a `pd.Series`, then `to_datetime` can return either:

   a) **In the ideal case**: a `pd.Series` with `dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]`

   b) If something unknown goes wrong: a `pd.Series` with `dtype: object` filled with `datetime.datetime` objects.

I don't know if this list of possibilities is complete or whether there are other options.

This can probably cause many problems when people try to use this. One example: in cases 1b and 2b, you can't use methods like `to_datetime(x).tz_convert(UTC)` etc...

All of this happens "silently", there is no error or warnings produced to let you know what you'll end up with. In my case, I'm ending up with large series time stamp string arrays turning into 1b and 2b.

At the moment I don't even how to find out *why* you sometimes end up with 1a and 1b. The documentation mentions that this can be related to whether your timestamps are outside the Timestamp-min and Timestamp.max boundaries set by pandas: I checked and this doesn't seem to be a problem for any of my timestamps.

So my questions are:

1. Does anyone know why this can happen?
2. How could I find out what the reason is and flag it and do something about it?
3. How to generally ensure I get the return type I want (i.e. something with a `dtype = datetime64..` or similar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: That's a very good point, but that's exactly part of the problem here. I get cases 1b and 2b when I use long timeseries with tens of thousands of elements, and I don't know which particular elements are causing the issue. If I use a small subset, I don't get the issue.

Comment: i think you have "null" or badly formatted values in your dataset

Comment: Passing `errors='coerce'` should always give `datetime64` objects, right?

Comment: Another reason could be that you have mixed UTC offsets specified in your input. If so, parse with `utc=True` and `tz_convert` to the correct time zone afterwards. Anyways, I think the question would benefit from a concrete example.

Comment: @MrFuppes actually that was the issue, I had data straddling a daytime savings shift. But I'm a little surprised as to why it needs to return an 'object' array in this situation. Would it not be possible to have a tz unaware datetime64 array?

Comment: The reason is that a UTC offset is not a time zone. If you have different UTC offsets, that makes timestamps with different tzinfo attributes. However those must be unique in a pd.Series (np.array) so that `datetime64[ns]` can be used. As I wrote, the "correct" way would be to parse to UTC and then convert to *one* specific time zone (=unique tzinfo). But you can also drop tz information by localizing to None, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16628819/10197418