# What is the purpose of using tz_localize after tz_convert to convert to local time zone?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

In a codebase I am looking at, I see the following

```
local_timezone = get_local_timezone()
df1["start_time"] = df1.start_time.dt.tz_convert(local_timezone) # pandas dataframe

df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=["start_time"])

df_merged["start_time"] = df_merged["start_time"].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

I've been under the impression that only either one of `tz_localize` and `tz_convert` is needed, and not both, to convert a timezone to the local timezone. What is the purpose of using both here?

Comment: I only see `tz_localize` being used here ...? What's the time zone used in `df2` ?

Comment: @FObersteiner. I guess `df2` is already tz-aware with `local_timezone`.

Comment: @FObersteiner I'm sorry. The first one should have been `tz_convert`. I just made the change

Comment: ok, so `df1` already has aware datetime, which you need to convert to the same timezone as `df2` before the merge. `tz_convert`: convert timezone, `tz_localize`: set timezone or remove it with None. See also [Convert pandas timezone-aware DateTimeIndex to naive timestamp, but in certain timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16628819/10197418) for the latter.

Comment: I see, I think that makes sense. If there wasn't a merge, and if you just had `df1["start_time"] = df1.start_time.dt.tz_convert(local_timezone)` and then `df1["start_time"] = df1["start_time"].dt.tz_localize(None)`, does this get redundant, because I think you can just do both ops at the same time IIUC?
`

Comment: I wouldn't say one of the steps is redundant; it depends on your application what you need further on.

Comment: Btw. `tz_convert` never changes the internal representation of the date/time. Only `tz_localize(None)` does that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656878/10197418) for example). I think Corraliens' answer is not accurate in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** after your edit:

You probably have 2 tz-aware dataframe but not in the same timezone. Maybe your first dataframe is `UTC` while the second one is `local_timezone`.

To allow merging on start_time column, the **dates should be aligned** (same date, same time, **same timezone**). Once the merge is done, you can safely remove the timezone information just for more aesthetic display... (avoid +XX:XX)

---

You probably have dataframes:

- `df1` with tz-naive datetime (with missing +XX:XX)
- `df2` with tz-aware datetime (with missing +XX:XX where +XX:XX is `local_timezone`

To allow merging on `start_time` column, the dates should be aligned (same date, same time, same timezone). Once the merge is done, you can remove the timezone and restore tz-naive datetime. That's why you have used `tz_localize` twice.

Using `tz_localize` doesn't modify the datetime but just append the information about timezone. Using `tz_convert` for already tz-aware datetime change the timezone AND the datetime.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the OP previously. The first one should have been `tz_convert` and not `tz_localize`. I believe this will change your answer

Comment: @David. I updated my answer with this new information. I also left my previous answer.