How to compare the current datetime with pd.to_datetime method with Pandas dataframe
I've had a scour of similar issues but the suggested actions haven't quite hit the mark.
I have series of times and electricity rates from an api call which are presented in the following format.
    value_inc_vat            valid_from              valid_to
99         19.152  2024-04-21T20:00:00Z  2024-04-21T20:30:00Z
98         16.800  2024-04-21T20:30:00Z  2024-04-21T21:00:00Z
97         16.989  2024-04-21T21:00:00Z  2024-04-21T21:30:00Z
96         12.873  2024-04-21T21:30:00Z  2024-04-21T22:00:00Z
95         14.574  2024-04-21T22:00:00Z  2024-04-21T22:30:00Z

I have stored them in a Pandas data frame and want to create a new dataframe where only entries with a valid_from datetime in the future are stored.
I took my data frame called rates and applied the pd.to_datetime method
rates['valid_from'] = pd.to_datetime(rates['valid_from'])
print(rates.head(5))

This gives the updated rates df as below
    value_inc_vat                valid_from              valid_to
99         19.152 2024-04-21 20:00:00+00:00  2024-04-21T20:30:00Z
98         16.800 2024-04-21 20:30:00+00:00  2024-04-21T21:00:00Z
97         16.989 2024-04-21 21:00:00+00:00  2024-04-21T21:30:00Z
96         12.873 2024-04-21 21:30:00+00:00  2024-04-21T22:00:00Z
95         14.574 2024-04-21 22:00:00+00:00  2024-04-21T22:30:00Z

However, when I try to check valid_from datetime in the future...
today = datetime.today()
print(pd.Timestamp(today))

futurerates = rates.loc[rates['valid_from'] >= today]

I get the TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects which I understand is saying my value today and valid_from are not of the same type.
Also TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC] and datetime
So obviously I need to get my today format and valid_from format the same, I tried adding the format argument to the pd.to_datetime method but I can't quite get the result I'm after.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628819/convert-pandas-timezone-aware-datetimeindex-to-naive-timestamp-but-in-certain-t

Is this what you're looking for? Compare timestamp with datetime

If that's not what you're looking for, please [edit] and add what you've already looked at. I found that question by just googling "pandas" and the first error message. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for more tips. (Showing your research is one of them.)

Change today to this -> pd.to_datetime('now').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
